# Build numbers table on the fly in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, data-generation

How do I return a rowset consisting of the last four years based on the current date?

If this query runs on 12/31/2010 it should return:

```
2007
2008
2009
2010
```

But if it is run on 1/1/2011 it should return:

```
2008
2009
2010
2011
```

Here's what I started with, two queries that return the starting year. I prefer the second as converting to string feels a bit dirty to me.

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(TRUNC(sysdate, 'YY') - INTERVAL '3' YEAR, 'YYYY') FROM DUAL;
SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM sysdate) - 3 FROM DUAL;
```

But I don't know how to generate rows to flesh this out. In SQL Server I'd use a CTE as in [the fn_nums function on this page](http://sqlservercode.blogspot.com/2007/04/interview-with-itzik-ben-gan-author-of.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
  SELECT yr
    FROM (    SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM (ADD_MONTHS ( SYSDATE, - ( (LEVEL - 1) * 12)))) yr
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4)
ORDER BY yr;
```

Or:

```
  SELECT yr
    FROM (    SELECT  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM sysdate) - (level -1 ) yr
                FROM DUAL
          CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4)
ORDER BY yr;
```

Or:

```
    SELECT yr
      FROM (SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM SYSDATE) - (x - 1) yr
              FROM DUAL
            MODEL
               DIMENSION BY (1 AS z)
               MEASURES (1 x)
               RULES
                  ITERATE (4)
                  (x [ITERATION_NUMBER] = ITERATION_NUMBER + 1))
  ORDER BY yr;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll be using `SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM sysdate) - LEVEL + 1 Yr FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4 ORDER BY Yr;`. Why make it more complicated?

Answer (score 6):

To display numbers from 1 to 100:

```
SELECT  LEVEL 
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 100
ORDER BY LEVEL
```

To change the max, change it in the third line.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me realize that `LEVEL` is a selectable value. It is unfortunate, though, that your response didn't actually answer the stated question.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the accepted answer you can replace the inline view with a with clause.  I find the with clause more readable.   In particular  if you are going to perform multiple calculations against the on-the-fly NUMBERS table as part of the same query - the entire SQL statement is more readable.

Numbers table on the fly:

```
WITH NUMBERS_START_AT_ZERO AS
     (SELECT LEVEL - 1 AS NUM 
       FROM DUAL
       CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 4
       order by NUM desc)
SELECT  EXTRACT (YEAR FROM sysdate) - NUM AS YEARS
  FROM NUMBERS_START_AT_ZERO
```

**Output:**

```
YEARS
2009
2010
2011
2012
```

Comment: Thanks for the detail, Brian. I did put my year dates into a CTE when I wrote this query.