# Create Oracle XML view

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing, clob

I have an Oracle table that stores a lot of data as XML in `CLOB`s.  For instance, it maps status integers to customized status names. Here's some simplified XML:

```
<metadata>
    <states>
        <state status="0" label="New" />
        <state status="1" label="Data-Entry" />
        <state status="25" label="Approve-Data" /> 
    </states>
</metadata>
```

I wrote a query to extract said XML from the database and determine status name given a status integer of 25:

```
select id As METADATA_ID, EXTRACTVALUE(xmltype(XML_STRING), '/metadata/states/state[@status="25"]/@label') from metadata;
```

Result: `342, "Approve-Data"`.  So far, so good. The query above creates a list of all the different labels for that state. What I'd like to do, though, is to create a view with the following columns:

```
METADATA_ID   |   STATUS_NUM   |    LABEL
342               0                 "New"
342               1                 "Data-Entry"
342               25                "Approve-Data"
674               3                 "Something-Else"
674               6                 "More-Data"
```

That way I could look up all the different mappings for the different metadata IDs and perform normal Oracle joins. Is there a way to do it, given that there's gaps in the status numbers?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible with straight SQL.  You might use PL/SQL and iterate over the range of possible `status` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news everyone! I found a solution using XMLTABLE (please pardon my arbitrary capitalization practices):

```
select 
  m.id as metadata_id, x.*
FROM
  metadata m,
  XMLTABLE('/metadata/states/state'
       PASSING xmltype(m.xml_string)
       COLUMNS status_id INTEGER PATH '@status',
               status_label VARCHAR(32) PATH '@label') x;
```

Answer (score 0):

You somehow need to multiply one row to the number of state tags that it has.

1st solution,

Make changes to EXTRACTVALUE so that it will return @status/label;@status/label; like 
0/New;1/Data-Entry;25/Approve-data

there is a problem of selecting separators /; so that you don't have them in your label.

Then [convert string to table](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=412)

2nd solution

[Create numbers table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521906/build-numbers-table-on-the-fly-in-oracle) and join it with your table. then instead of `state[@status="25"]` use `state[i]` where i will come from numbers table

3rd solution

following the first link in this answer you can find example with XMLSEQUENCE to extract rows