# Is there any way I can speed up the following insert(s)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Is there any way of speeding up this piece of code?

```
FOR j IN 1..max
LOOP
  INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500), DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500));
END LOOP;
```

The loop is gonna happen for at least a million times, so a million+ inserts. I know about FORALL, but that is for collections of data that already exists.. not really helpful for me. So I was wondering if there's a better way than a classic loop, or at least some other improvements that I can do(like adding/removing some options when I create the table), anything that can make this run faster.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try different transaction sizes?

Comment: How long does it take to run it and how much do you want to speed it up?

Comment: A bit better that use a local `variable` for `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500)` and then use it ;).

Comment: Your problem is that you're inserting one row at a time.  You need to find a way to do this as a set.  Some hints and tips are here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521906/build-numbers-table-on-the-fly-in-oracle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You might want to try to use a single insert statement instead of executing a statement a million times:

```
insert into myTable
  select
    dbms_random.value(1, 500),
    dbms_random.value(1, 500)
  from
    dual
  connect by
    level <= 1*1000*1000;
```

On a side note: did you measure how much time is spent on executing `dbms_random` and how much time on *actually* inserting the values?

Answer (score 5):

A million rows inserted during a single transaction is going to use up a lot of space in your UNDO tablespace. A better choice IMO is to use some intermediate commits to reduce the span of the transactions. Thus, building on @ReneNyffenegger's answer, I suggest something like the following:

```
DECLARE
  nRows_inserted  NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..1000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE
      SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500),
             DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500)
        FROM DUAL
        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;

    nRows_inserted := nRows_inserted + SQL%ROWCOUNT;

    COMMIT;
  END LOOP;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(nRows_inserted || ' rows inserted into MY_TABLE');
END;
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 : Although, 1000 seems very small for such a narrow insert (2 fields).  The OP should play with this value until they see diminishing returns :)

Comment: At 1000 the math is easier...although I'm still trying to count it all out on my fingers... :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer!