# Follow up on earlier today: Is there any way I can speed up the following insert(s)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Sorry to bother again but I need an answer to this question since I can't seem to come up with one myself. 
Here's the previous post: [Is there any way I can speed up the following insert(s)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961325/is-there-any-way-i-can-speed-up-the-following-inserts).

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
        (
        random_value1 NUMBER,
        random_value2 NUMBER,
        random_string VARCHAR2(5)
        );

DECLARE
  TYPE arrayType IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(5);
  v_my_array arrayType := arrayType('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux');
  max NUMBER := 1000000;
BEGIN
  FOR j IN 1..max
  LOOP
    INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500), 
      DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500), v_my_array(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 5)));
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Based on the answers I got on the previous post I can easily insert random values on the columns #1 and #2 using a single insert statement instead of a million(see the example). Now my question is how can I also insert a random string from a list of given strings and avoid using a loop, if that's possible of course.
If I try something like:

```
INSERT INTO myTable
  SELECT
    DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500),
    DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500),
    v_my_array(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 5))
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY
    LEVEL <= 1000000;
```

I get the same value for column #3 on all the rows, when I want different results everytime("random" results).

Once again, thanks for taking the time to look over this!

Comment: @KrisGruttemeyer , Zane -  It's a valid question. It builds upon the previous answer that was accepted rather than saying it doesn't work. And the solution for this might require him to use a subquery.

Comment: You say in your previous post that you are familiar with FORALL but can´t use it as it is meant for pre-populated collections. Why not declare a collection an populate it in a for-loop and then subsequently use it in a FORALL? If SGA/PGA consumption is a concern because of the volume wrap it all up in an outer loop doing say 100k each loop.

Comment: I think the question is that the array subscript always uses the same value in the sql for all rows when the OP uses the syntax `v_my_array(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 5))`. He wants something like `v_my_array(3)` for first row and `v_my_array(1)` for the second row and so on. I don't think that would be possible in plain sql. But i'm still thinking about the best way to do this.

Comment: This might work: `INSERT INTO myTable
  SELECT n1, n2, v_my_array(n3) FROM (SELECT DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500) n1, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500) n2, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 5) n3 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000000) x;`

Comment: @ruudvan I have no Oracle available now to test but how did the OP's query (which has `v_my_array(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 5))`) did not error? `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 5)` is not a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE arrayType IS VARRAY(5) OF VARCHAR2(5);
  v_my_array arrayType := arrayType('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux');
  max NUMBER := 1000000;
  TYPE t_data IS TABLE OF myTable%ROWTYPE INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  v_data t_data;
  v_row  myTable%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10
  LOOP
     FOR j IN 1..100000
     LOOP
       v_row.random_value1 := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500);
       v_row.random_value2 := DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500);
       v_row.random_string := v_my_array(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 5));
       v_data(j) := v_row;
     END LOOP;
     FORALL k IN INDICIES OF v_data
       INSERT INTO myTable VALUES v_Data(k);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

What about this approach to put strings into subquery

```
INSERT INTO myTable

SELECT
   DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500),
   DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 500),
   myvarchar.a
FROM 
(select a from
(
SELECT 'foo' a from dual
union 
select 'bar' a from dual
union 
select 'baz' a from dual
union 
select 'qux' a from dual
union 
select 'quux' a from dual
 )
ORDER BY 
DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM) myvarchar
CONNECT BY
LEVEL <= 10;
 /
```

This select statement returns over 12 mil rows, so scale appropriately.
I run it for LEVEl<=7 and 97k rows. On my machine it took 3 seconds.